# Unable to setup contact form hosted on namecheap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, namecheap

I have a contact form hosted on namecheap.com. I am trying to use the following code to send an email from a contact form.

HTML Form:

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="#">
    <p class="contact-name">
        <input id="contact_name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value="" name="name" />
    </p>
    <p class="contact-email">
        <input id="contact_email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" value="" name="email" />
    </p>
    <p class="contact-message">
        <textarea id="contact_message" placeholder="Your Message" name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p class="contact-submit">
        <a id="contact-submit" class="submit" href="#">Send Your Email</a>
    </p>

    <div id="response">

    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#contact-submit").on('click',function() {
    $contact_form = $('#contact-form');

    var fields = $contact_form.serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "_include/php/contact.php",
        data: fields,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
          console.log('ABOUT TO SEND');
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log('response', response);
            if(response.status){
                $('#contact-form input').val('');
                $('#contact-form textarea').val('');
            }

            $('#response').empty().html(response.html);
        },
        failure: function(error) {
            console.log('error', error);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
POST http://taohgreen.me/_include/php/contact‌​.php 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.min.js:5
```

It seems to be a problem with namecheap blocking emails from outside sources. So I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction of how to resolve this.

One thing I was thinking is that if I could host my php script on a different website then I wouldn't have any of these issues and would also have a simple reusable script. But I also am not sure if there is an easy way to do that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is contact.php returning 500?

Comment: yes the exact error is
`POST http://taohgreen.me/_include/php/contact.php 500 (Internal Server Error)     jquery.min.js:5`

Comment: well then perhaps that would be the code to show